How do i present a table with 4 "dimensions"
What would be a good design for the user to interact with a dataset that has 4 "dimensions", and one of them is editable. It's presented on web, so i have all kind of user interaction in the possibility space.
A made up example, in a table:

I can put "Type of animal" as columns (dimension 1)
I can put "Part of animal" as rows (dimension 2)
I can put the color of the animals body part in the actual cell (dimension 3) - a single value will be shown at a time here
When i want to add a 4th dimension in here, i get into trouble. Say for example "continent"

Possible solution 1
Replicate the entire table one after another with "continent" as a heading. Takes much space, and all will probably not all be visible at the same time. Tabs instead?

Possible solution 2
Cram all the continents into each cell as a label, followed by the color. The table will be larger but still smaller than previous example. Will be very visually busy.

Anyone with experience solving, or has seen this solved in an elegant way?

Does the user have the possibility to interact, for example by clicking a button, or are the tables static?

@Danielillo The color dimension is editable, and can have a single value

Ok, I guess there's no interaction available, the user can not click a button to change the parent "dimension", because this is the immediate solution

Yes, interactions are a possiblity. This is presented on web

You should edit the question and add this information as it is essential to understand it and be able to evaluate an answer.

In order to preserve the best visualization, you can use maps or filters. Do not use Possible Solution 2!... It does not present the data clearly and easy to understand to the user.

Interaction greatly reduces the complexity of representing a table with multiple entries. It is as simple as setting interactive parent categories and filtering the table content.
A clear and much more complex example is the Population Distribution by Race/Ethnicity table.
In this case there are:

Three modes of representation:

Table
Map
Graph


A drop-down menu for each time period

Three filters:

Data view
Distributions
Locations


A plus: Tools Panel



